# htmlentities shows all chars but doesn't execute them

Tags: php

I currently have the problem that the `htmlentities` function **shows all the special chars** like `<`, `>`, `"`, `'` and the function **doesn't convert** them to something like `&#039;`.

However it doesn't execute things like `<script>alert("test");</script>`, it just displays it.

Is there any problem? If yes, how can I solve this?

My primary intention behind the `htmlentities` things is to be 100% safe against XSS attacks.

**Example Code**

```
$string = '<script>alert("test");</script>';
echo htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: for XSS htmlentities is the wrong function. normaly you use htmlspecialchars. that's enough! htmlentities does more than you need.

Comment: Are you viewing this back in the browser? Because the browser will decode those special sequences and 'display' them. Check the source to see if it's actually encoded, or test it out using error_log instead of echo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't see the character codes unless you view the page source, because your browser is automatically converting the encoded characters for readability.

The fact that you can see them means that they are escaped and rendering properly.